# got error when i try to run WebService in Debug

Tags: c#, web-services

got error when i try to run WebService in Debug

this error:

```
error while trying to run project: Unable to start Debugging on the Web server.
Debbuging failed because integrated windows authentication is not enable.
```

i work on C# with Visual-studio 2003 (this is old customer project)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable windows authentication on IIS.

- IIS 7/7.5 instructions are [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628%28WS.10%29.aspx).
- IIS 6 instructions are [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1aa70bfa-add5-4f61-9c7b-a095c1bd4306.mspx?mfr=true).